# Need help in Optimizing the below jquery code

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to Optimize the below lines of code?

```
        $('#state').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
        $('#city').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
        $('#branch').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
        $('#branchAddress').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

I have tried adding all the fields by comma seperated, but it is not working.

Please help to optimize the above code.

Comment: Are there other `select`elements if so plz show the html (or at least the selects)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like :

```
$('#state, #city, #branch, #branchAddress')
    .each(function(i,item){$('option:not(:first)',$(item)).remove();});
```

or like this :

```
$('#state, #city, #branch, #branchAddress').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

at last (but I wouldn't call it optimization ;-)

```
$('#state option:not(:first), #city option:not(:first), #branch option:not(:first), #branchAddress option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Comment: You're right about the not-working-children/working-find methods... I'll try to find out why.

Comment: @sp00m and $('#state,#city,#branch,#branchAddress').children('option:not(:first-child)').remove(); seems to be working...

Comment: Haha, awesome, here is mine: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/13686415/1225328](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13686415/1225328). I guess we came across the same answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#branchAddress #state #city #branchAddress').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Its possible to have multple elements in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

add the same class to all of the above and refer to it once instead of referring to the ID's multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The following should do (see also [jQuery multiple-selector api](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/))

```
$('#state, #city, #branch, #branchAddress').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```