# jQuery's multiple selector + find() vs children()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find, children

```html
<select id="select1">
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
</select>​
```

Behavior of the `find()` and the `children()` methods:

**`find()`**:

```js
$('#select1, #select2').find('option:not(:first)').remove();​​​​​​
```

Works as expected: `select1` has only option `11` and `select2` has only option `21`

**`children()`**:

```js
$('#select1, #select2').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Works weirdly: `select1` has only option `11` but `select2` has no option anymore...

**Why?**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tyZzy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see

```
$('#select1, #select2').find('option:not(:first)')
```

is equal to

```
$('#select1  option:not(:first), #select2  option:not(:first)')
```

not

```
$('#select1, #select2').children('option:not(:first)')
```

Think about the context selector as it's the same as using .find()

```
$('option:not(:first)',$('#select1, #select2'))
```

By using children with first.. you are only getting the first children option returned in collection.. whereas the context/find selector looks for the first in each context

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain why the `.find` is working with `:first`, but the `.children` isn't working with `:first` because `:first` gets the first selected element in the set of selected elements, not the ones that are the first child. What you want is `:first-child`.

```
// children
$('#select1, #select2').children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();

// find
$('#select3, #select4').find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tyZzy/2/

This may be a bug, though it needs more research.

Comment: Very nice solution! You could also use `each()` http://jsfiddle.net/tyZzy/1/, however, your answer is much easier.