# jQuery difference between find() and children() when combined with :first

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the process of answering the following jQuery question [Need help in Optimizing the below jquery code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13685141/1236044) , I stumbled across another question about `.find()` and `.children()`.

The question was, given four selectboxes with ids **state**, **city**, **branch**, **branchAddress**, to remove all but the first option for each select boxes.

There has been several answers posted. Among those were :

1. `$('#state,#city,#branch,#branchAddress').children('option:not(:first)').remove();`
2. `$('#state,#city,#branch,#branchAddress').children('option:not(:first-child)').remove();`
3. `$('#state,#city,#branch,#branchAddress').find('option:not(:first)').remove();`

Solution 1 does not seem to work (removing all options, except the first option of the first select box) according to this js fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/QkNRf/1/ )

Solution 2 and 3 seem to work perfectly.

I would be glad if someone could point me what I missed, or explain to me why solution 3 works where solution 1 does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the other answers are correct but I think the important part in the doc that explains why example 1 fails and why number 3 works is that while `.children()` effectively filters the results from the previous selector, `.find()` will perform [selector-context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) search, so (I assume) it will perform the `'option:not(:first)'` search in all 4 contexts and collate the results, while `.children()` will first collate the results and then filter using `'option:not(:first)'` effectively removing all but the very first...

The depth of search is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: thx also @roasted ! I guess the .children() doc is somewhat misleading. Most people seem to think that the only difference with .find() lies in the search depth.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs: [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Comment: thx for your answer. but my example is about select boxes and their options, so no more than one level deep. Why would there be a difference between solution 1 and solution 3 ? (solution 1 does not work, where solution 3 does). They just differ on the find/children.